# Identification of points on a torus

Tags: conformal-field-theory

Consider the following paragraph from page 214-215 of these [notes](http://www.hartmanhep.net/topics2015/25-microstates).

> Consider a $2$d QFT (not necessarily conformal yet) on a Euclidean torus. The most
>   general torus is specified by two lattice vectors $\vec{v}_{1}$, $\vec{v}_{2}$ on the $(t_{E},\phi)$ plane, meaning that we identify all points related by
>   $$(t_{E},\phi) \sim (t_{E},\phi) + m\vec{v}_{1} + n\vec{v}_{2}, \qquad m,n \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

I do not see why two lattice vectors are needed to identify all the points of a torus. After all, the torus is a two-dimensional surface, so isn't a **single** two-dimensional lattice vector enough to identify all the points of a torus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two-dimensional lattice vector specifies a single direction in space. The set of points $\{m\vec{v}_1\}$ describes a *line** on the torus. As such, in order to specify a point on a torus, you need one other lattice vector, and it must not be a scalar multiple of the first.

It is a basic fact of linear algebra that an $n$-dimensional space requires $n$ vectors for a basis. Therefore, a 2-dimensional space requires 2 basis vectors.

*Well, it's a line on the "unrolled" coordinates, anyway. On the torus, it's a helix or a circle.

Comment: It's slightly disingenuous for me to say that this is a consequence of linear algebra, as this is not a manifold that's homeomorphic to the plane; however, there is an analogous condition for arbitrary vector spaces.